# Running web-component-tester offline

Tags: node.js, selenium, polymer-2.x, web-component-tester

I installed web-component-server using `npm install -g web-component-tester`. After that, I ran `wct` on a simple test that I had written only in chrome. Subsequently, I moved to an environment where it is impossible for me to connect to internet at all times. Since i had already run wct once, I expected it to run again. But re-running the command `wct --verbose -l chrome` gave following error:

```
Error: Could not request headers from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.11.1/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64.zip
: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com:443
```

It seems to want Mozilla selenium drivers which I have not even specified to run in my command! How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the install check (that only works online) with
`wct --skip-selenium-install`

Comment: To switch this on permanently, add it to your wct.conf.json. Here's mine:

    {
      "plugins": {
        "local": {
          "skipSeleniumInstall": true
        }
      }
    }